# PrestaShop home slider not working if swiped manually

Tags: php, slider, prestashop, shopping-cart

I have a problem in home slider. Once the slider image is swiped manually, it doesn't swipe automatically again. I have to refresh the page to start the the "auto play/auto swipe" feature.

Auto play is checked in admin for the slider.

How can I resume the "auto play/auto swipe" feature if the slider has been swiped?

Comment: Are you using default prestashop theme?

Comment: no, but home slider is default

Comment: Are you getting any firebug error while swiping?

Comment: no, there isn't any error, when swipped manually, it works well, but then autoswipe is not working

Comment: Try to uninstall, delete and then reinstall it.

Comment: tried, it didn't work

Comment: You have to show your code on fiddle. Then only anyone help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72576/discussion-between-anant-kumar-singh-and-baig772).